# How do I order the x axis chronologically, put more numbers in the y axis, and get the mean() and median() functions to work with my excel data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

So I'm trying to make box and whisker plots for my weekly/monthly profit and loss for my sports betting picks for each day. [Here is a google sheet with my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z6J62oeQPsR5K5Y70ye2fTJ5wgQfOaj9bEP0eTibS7U/edit?usp=sharing).

Below is an image of what my code has gotten me so far
[image]

And following that here is my code

```
exceldata <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\User-Ryzen\\Downloads\\Profit_Loss.xlsx") 

df <- data.frame(exceldata)

month <- c(df$month)
week <- c(df$week)
p_l <- c(df$profit_loss)

library(tidyverse)

qplot(x=month, y=p_l, geom="boxplot", fill=month, xlab="Month", ylab="Profit/Loss")
```

Here are the following things I'd like to be able to do in the plot:

1.) Instead of ordering the x axis alphabetically, have it ordered chronologically (i.e. January goes first, April goes last)
2.) Make the y axis go from -500 to 750 in intervals of 100

The last thing I would like to do is find out the mean and median for each week and month. I thought I could do this by using mean(month) and so forth, but that gave me this error:

"In mean.default(month) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Thanks for all the help and please let me know if this needs clarification!

Comment: Please provide data in form, we can easily reproduce your problem. You can run command `dput(df)` and copy the output as a code to your question. If your data is too long, copy only a few rows: `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# example data
set.seed(1337)
data <- list(
  Jan = rnorm(100, mean = -300, sd = 100),
  Feb = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 100),
  Mar = rnorm(100, mean = 500, sd = 100)
) %>%
  enframe(name = "month", value = "profit_loss") %>%
  unnest()
#> Warning: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
#> Please use `cols = c(profit_loss)`

data <- mutate(data, month = month %>% factor(levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar")))

data %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(
    median = median(profit_loss),
    mean = mean(profit_loss)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   month median    mean
#>   <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Jan   -281.  -276.  
#> 2 Feb    -13.2    4.11
#> 3 Mar    496.   484.

qplot(month, profit_loss, data = data, geom = "boxplot") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-500, 750, by = 100), limits = c(-500, 750))
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>